# Hamburger dropdown overlapped by Hero image content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a dynamic clip-path dropping down from the top-right corner on the hamburger menu click. Everything works fine except the content from my Hero image is overlapping. I tried z-index, but these are all position absolute so it has no effect. If I change the position it screws up the whole page. This project is being built in Django, but that doesn't seem to matter much here.

HTML

```html
{% load static %}

<header class="nav-down">
  <nav>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'news' %}">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'library' %}">Library</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'search' %}">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```css
/* ===========================================
    RESET CSS BEGIN*
   =========================================== */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

#html-container {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 81px;
}

/*RESET CSS END*/

.showcase {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
    ),
    url(/static/img/vg_home.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.showcase-content-top {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.showcase-content-top h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.text-color {
  color: rgb(151, 193, 92);
}

#wave {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px solid silver;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34.15%;
  left: 46.2%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: pulseEffect 4s infinite linear;
  animation: pulseEffect 4s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulseEffect {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
    border: 0px solid silver;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    border: 10px solid rgb(151, 193, 92);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes pulseEffect {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.separator {
  color: rgb(151, 193, 92);
}

.sub {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.showcase-content-buttons > ul {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.showcase-content-buttons a {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.showcase-content-buttons a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(151, 193, 92);
  border: 1px solid rgb(151, 193, 92);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

/* ===========================================
      NAV BAR STYLING  //  START
     =========================================== */

header {
  background: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  height: 81px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
  top: -81px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 81px;
  background: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

/*Navigation Bar styling  //  END*/

/* ===========================================
      About Page Styling  //  Start
     =========================================== */

.about-container {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 65%;
  height: 85%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.05);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.about-container h6 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 250px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.about-container .large {
  color: rgba(114, 245, 190);
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.about-container .paragraph {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
/*About Page Styling  //  End*/

/* ===========================================
       FOOTER STYLES //  START
  =============================================*/
#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 81px;
  margin-top: -81px;
  background: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 1;
}

.footer-content {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.page-content > p > img {
  max-width: 2vh;
  height: auto;
}

p.logos {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

footer h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(151, 193, 92);
}
/*FOOTER STYLES END*/

/* ============= RESPONSIVE max-width: 991p =========== */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #wave {
    display: none;
  }

  .hamburger i {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
    top: 25%;
    right: -30%;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  nav {
    position: relative;
  }

  .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgb(151, 193, 92);
    height: 81px;
    width: 100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-5%, 0%);
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(151, 193, 92);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -20%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -20%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1400px at 100% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1400px at 100% -10%);
    pointer-events: all;
  }
}
/* ============= RESPONSIVE max-width: 768px =========== */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
}
/* ============= RESPONSIVE max-width: 385px=========== */
@media screen and (max-width: 385px) {
}
```

Before the dropdown is initiated

[image: HTML before hamburger menu dropdown]

An image of what it looks like once the dropdown is fully encompensing the screen

[image: Chrome inspector view of debugging HTML page]

Comment: Add `z-index` to `<header>` larger value than to **hero image main div **.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I asked it too quickly. I just needed to give the header tag a z-index, not the nav tag. Working now.